# Modified knapsack problem gets stuck in infinite loop

Tags: tree, bioinformatics, traversal, knapsack-problem

I've been trying to implement a **modified knapsack problem algorithm** regarding **bioinformatics**.

What I have so far is, in my opinion, pretty close to the solution, but the program gets stuck at a certain point.

I have a list of nodes which have mass (of a certain amino-acid), index, and list of nodes that they can get to.

**NODE**:

```
class Node():
def __init__(self, mass, index):
    self.mass = mass
    self.prev = []
    self.next = []
    self.index = index


def chainTo(self, next):
    self.next.append(next)
    next.prev.append(self)
```

The goal is to find the longest chain possible from given nodes so I could then find from their masses which peptide do they represent.

To do that, I have written a function that goes through the list of all nodes and chains them to one another if **nodes[i].mass - nodes[j].mass** is equal to some amino-acid mass which are predefined in a .txt file.

```
def createTree(massTable, massDev, aminoTable, extras):
    nodes = createNodes()

    for i in range(0, len(nodes)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nodes)):
            findAmino(nodes[i], nodes[j], massTable, massDev, aminoTable, extras)

    return nodes

def findAmino(first, second, massTable, massDev, aminoTable, extras):
found = False
for amino, mass in massTable.items():
    for extra, extraMass in extras.items():
        #print(first.mass - second.mass)
        if ((mass + extraMass - massDev) <= abs(first.mass - second.mass) <= (mass + extraMass + massDev)):
            first.chainTo(second) #pravimo vezu
            #print(amino)
            aminoTable.update({(first, second) : amino})
            found = True
            break

return False if not found else True #ako ne nađe niti jednu mogućnost, vraća False
```

So the final and the main part of the code is the tree-traversing algorithm which follows specific rules:

1. Take the first node from the list (if it has no nodes in its next list, take the second one, and so on)
2. Call the tree-traversal algorithm to find all possible paths (for example, if node[0] has node[1] and node[2] in its next list, then the tree-traversal algorithm has to find path node[0]->node[1] and node[0]->node[2]
3. From all the generated paths, the program takes the longest one
4. Program repeats step 1 but it doesn't take the first node from the list, but rather the one after the last in the longest found path
5. When it comes to the last node, it ends and returns list of longest possible chains.

```
def traverseRoot(root, chains):
    traverse(root, [], chains)

#node - čvor na kojem se nalazimo
#ako nema susjede, u chains dodajemo taj put
#ako ima, pokrecemo isti algoritam
def traverse(node, path, chains):
    path.append(node)
    if(len(node.next) == 0):
        chains.append(path)
    else:
        for i in node.next:
            print(str(i.mass) + " " + str(i.index))
            traverse(i, path.copy(), chains)


def start(nodes, massTable, massDev, extras):
        #IDEJA:
        #1. funkcija uzima prvi čvor (ukoliko nema prijelaze, uzima idući, pa idući, itd.)
        #2. nad tim čvorom provodi neku vrstu tree-traversing algoritma kako bi prošao sve puteve
        #3. uzima kao konačni put onaj koji je došao najdalje u listi / pokrio najviše čvorova
        #4. ponavlja sve počevši od prvog koraka samo što ne uzima prvi čvor nego onaj koji dolazi nakon zadnjeg u prethodno pronađenom putu
        #5. kad dođe do zadnjeg čvora, prestaje sa radom i vraća listu stvorenih lanaca po čijim čemo vezama gledati koje aminokiseline predstavljaju
        start = 0
        finalChains = []
        while(True):
            currentNodeChains = []
            found = False
            for i in range(start, len(nodes)):
                if(not nodes[i].next): #1.
                    continue
                else:
                    found = True
                    print(start)
                    traverseRoot(nodes[i], currentNodeChains) #2.
                    break
            
            if (not found):
                return finalChains
                
            #3.
            maxLen = 0
            maxChain = None
            for chain in currentNodeChains:
                if (len(chain) > maxLen):
                    maxLen = len(chain)
                    maxChain = chain
            if (maxChain != None):
                finalChains.append(maxChain)
                print([i for i in maxChain])
                print("-----------")
                start = maxChain[-1].index + 1 #4.
        return finalChains
```

My whole problem is that the program gets stuck at a certain point.

For example, I have 300 nodes, and it gets stuck in an infinite loop somewhere towards the end, around 280th node in the example that I'm running it on.

I doubt that it has to do something with this specific example that I'm running, but more probably there is a logical error somewhere in the recursive function calls.

If anyone has a clue as where would the problem lie, I would much appreciate any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to debug the code, the problem seemed to be in the whole concept of the attribute **next** in the **Node** class.

When I printed out all of the Nodes' next lists, I found multiple occurences of the same Node, for example [2,2,2,3,8,...] so when I converted the **list to set** it didn't get stuck anymore.

Hope this helps someone in the future.